# Post data Spring web services Restful

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I am trying to save data on my database with a web service POST wich serializes a HTML form to save a object. The rest client firefox says this:

> "The server refused this request because the requested entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method"

The eclipse console shows the message:

> org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils - safeGetParameter called on a POST HttpServletRequest for LogoutRequest.  Cannot complete check safely.  Reverting to standard behavior for this Parameter

I understand that the object that i want to save is not valid, but I don't see what the problem is.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/solicitudCita", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public @ResponseBody String putSolicitud(@ModelAttribute("Solicitud") Solicitud solicitud) throws Exception{
    System.out.println(solicitud.toString());
    solicitudCitaAppMService.createOrUpdate(solicitud);
    String solicitudAdded = "Solicitud de cita -> {" + solicitud.toString() + "} añadida";
    System.out.println(solicitud);
    return solicitudAdded;
}
```

Help me please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call this controller in a RESTful manner, you have to annotate the solicitud parameter as @RequestBody. Second, you have to have the Jackson libraries in you classpath so Spring can pick them up and use them for unmarshalling the object.

If you use Maven, use these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

BTW, why do you have to serialize the HTML form and sent it across? I would suggest you use a REST client, for instance [this one](http://restforchrome.blogspot.com/), that is available in the Chrome WebStore.

Comment: I want to save the data of my form in a database table, for this reason I use the serialize method. For try this POST service I' using Rest CLient firefox (for example).  this dependencies have just in my pom.xml.